# My declared state is not being picked up?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this code and every time I typed "localhost:3000/page1" nothing happens i get cannot get /page1, this is the code..

```
var module = angular.module('ngFirstApp',['ui.router']);

module.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state("home",{ url: "/", template: "This is home"  })
        .state("page1",{ url: "/page1", template: "this is page"});

    // Prety the URL
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true,requireBase: false}); 
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/"); // always declare this for any URL that might be typed

});
```

please im losing my mind.. how come  when I put a gibberish url it doesnt takes me back to the "/" state???? whats wrong!?? im soo frustrated with this.. hours and hours looking for answers..

**UPDATE**: 
Heres my server.js code as well if it might help, If youre wondering if I added the UI-router, I did in my html and double check no error in dev tool network tab.. sigh so frustrated.

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var path    = require('path');  // native js node path

// set routing to ejs and change its default view folder
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views',path.resolve(__dirname,'client','views'));

// serve static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

// set our main ejs view index file
app.get('/',function(req, res){
    res.render('views/index');// use the render to use ejs templating
})

// make app listen to port 3000 or any port
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server is running... at port: '+ 3000);
})
```

Comment: Check if there are any errors in console log

Comment: Try localhost/page1 whether its working or not. If working then you have CORS issue.

Comment: I check the console its just a normal  [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 7ms] error...I strip the code to bare and still dont know why its not picking up the page1 url...ughhaa .. @digi what is CORS issue?

Comment: You need to add server-side rewrite rules.  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Answer (score 1):

I can see that your application is deployed in `local server` then based on the type of server you're using, you'll have to specify the `web application name` before just navigating it to the page of the application.

Suppose your deployed application is `'movies'`, then `localhost:3000/movies` will take you to default indexing of the movies directory i.e where your web application is initialized.

So in your case try `localhost:3000/yourdirectory/page1` this might help you!

Comment: Any comment or suggestion is welcomed! thank you il have a look at this, im not going anywhere just trying to fix this.. ugh thanks again